# Why $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}=k\right)=\sum_{s_1+\cdots+s_n=k}\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1},\ldots,X_{n}=s_{n}\right)$ in Bernouli experiment?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation

**Problem ( Bernouli experiment ) :**
We repeat some experiment ( for example, tossing a coin ) $ n $ times, where each experiment can end in success or failure. It is known that the probability for the success of each experiment separately is $ p \in (0,1) $. And that all the experiments are independent. What is the probability that there will be exactly $k$ successes out of $ n $ experiments?

**Solution ( from lecture notes ):**
The probability space that corresponds to a single experiment is $ \left(\{0,1\}, \mathbb{P}_{1}\right) $, where $ \mathbb{P(1)} = p $ ( success ) and $ \mathbb{P(0)} = 1-p $ ( failure ). The corresponding space for $ n $ independent experiments is the product space
$ (\Omega, \mathbb{P})=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}\left(\{0,1\}, \mathbb{P}_{1}\right) $
Denote as $ A_k $ the event in which the $k$-th experiment succeeded. From the given, it holds that $ \mathbb{P}(A_k) = p $ and $ A_1,...,A_n $ are independent. Denote the indicators of these events as $ X_1,...,X_n  $, correspondingly.
From the definition of independence-ship of the events it occurs that these variables are independent. In addition $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=0\right)=1-p, \mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=1\right)=p$
For the sake of further calculations, we'll denote it shortly as:
$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=s_{i}\right)=p^{s_{i}}(1-p)^{1-s_{i}}, \forall s_{i} \in\{0,1\}$.
Define the random variable $ N = X_1 + \cdots + X_n $.
Notice that $\{N=k\}=\left\{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}=k\right\}=\{$ exactly $k$ experiments out of $n$ succeeded   $\}$  $\color{red}{\text{And it occurs that  } }   $
$\mathbb{P}(N=k)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}=k\right)=\sum_{s_{1}+\cdots+s_{n}=k} \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}=s_{n}\right)$
Where the sum is on all $ s_1,...,s_n \in \{ 0,1 \} $ such that their sum is $k $. From independence-ship we'll get that for all $ s_1,...,s_n \in \{ 0,1 \} $ it occurs that
$\begin{aligned} \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}=s_{n}\right) &=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}\right) \ldots \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=s_{n}\right) \\ &=\prod_{i=1}^{n} p^{s_{i}}(1-p)^{1-s_{i}}=p^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_{i}}(1-p)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_{i}} \end{aligned}$
Meaning if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_{i} = k $ ( meaning there'll be exactly $ k $ successes out of $ n $ ) then $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}=s_{n}\right)=p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$
Hence,
$\begin{aligned} \mathbb{P}(N=k) &=\sum_{s_{1}+\cdots+s_{n}=k} \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}=s_{n}\right) \\ &=\sum_{s_{1}+\cdots+s_{n}=k} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right) p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} \end{aligned}$

And notice that from Newton's binomial formula, it occurs that
$\mathbb{P}(0 \leq N \leq n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb{P}(N=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right) p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=(p+(1-p))^{n}=1$
$ \square $

**My Questions:**

1. Why $\mathbb{P}(A_k) = p$ and not $ \mathbb{P}(A_k) = p^k $?
2. In the line where it says " $\mathbb{P}(N=k)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}=k\right)=\sum_{s_{1}+\cdots+s_{n}=k} \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}=s_{n}\right)$ " ( near red marking above), how is the transition $ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}=k\right) = \sum_{s_{1}+\cdots+s_{n}=k} \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=s_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}=s_{n}\right)$ justified? how the fact that $X_1,...,X_n $ are independent is used here? I can't see how $ \sigma $-additivity is used here.

**Notations:**

- $ (\Omega, \mathbb{P})=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}\left( \Omega_i, \mathbb{P}_i\right) \iff (\Omega, \mathbb{P}) = ( \Omega_1 \times \cdots \times \Omega_n  , \mathbb{P}_1 \cdots \mathbb{P}_n ) $
- $ \mathbb{P}(A,B) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B ) $

Also, all the discussion above relates to **discrete probability spaces** ( I don't  learn about continuous probability spaces in the course )

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 1) because $A_k$ ignores all other experiments. -- 2) The events of the summands are **mutually exclusive** and exhaust the event on the left hand side, hence the left probability is the sum of the individual event probabilities. Independence comes into play only later, when the summands are expressed as products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1.**

By definition, $A_k$ is the event where the $k^{th}$ experiment is a success, meaning
\begin{align}
A_k &= \{\omega\in \Omega\,:\, \omega_k=1\}\\
&= \underbrace{\{0,1\}\times \cdots \times \{0,1\}}_{\text{$k-1$ times}}\times \{1\}
\times \underbrace{\{0,1\}\times \cdots \times \{0,1\}}_{\text{$n-k$ times}}
\end{align}
What is the measure of this set? Well, by definition $\Bbb{P}$ is the $n$-fold product of the measure $\Bbb{P}_1$, so
\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}(A_k)&=\Bbb{P}_1(\{0,1\})^{k-1}\cdot \Bbb{P}_1(\{1\})\cdot \Bbb{P}_1(\{0,1\})^{n-k}\\
&=1^{k-1}\cdot p\cdot 1^{n-k}\\
&=p.
\end{align}

---

**Question 2.**

For each $s=(s_1,\dots, s_n)\in \{0,1\}^n$, let us consider the event
$B_s=\{X_1=s_1,\dots, X_n=s_n\}$, or more formally, $B_s= \{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X_1(\omega)=s_1,\dots, X_n(\omega)=s_n\}$, and consider the set $\mathcal{S}_k$ of all $s\in\{0,1\}^n$ such that $s_1+\cdots + s_n=k$. Then, we can write
\begin{align}
\{N=k\}&=\bigcup_{s\in \mathcal{S}_k}B_s,
\end{align}
and the latter is a disjoint collection of sets (so you have to show the two set inclusions $\subset$ and $\supset$, and also that the sets on the right are pairwise disjoint). Thus, by additivity of measures (a trivial consequence of $\sigma$-additivity), we have
\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}(\{N=k\})&=\sum_{s\in \mathcal{S}_k}\Bbb{P}(B_s)\\
&=\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}_k}\Bbb{P}(\{X_1=s_1\})\cdots \Bbb{P}(\{X_n=s_n\}),
\end{align}
where the last line used independence.